# Obtain time from apache tomcat API call

Tags: java, gwt, time, server, tomcat7

I have deployed a gwt project on apache tomcat 7, I want to do operations in java at certain time, I want obtain time from the server Tomcat. How can I get time from tomcat and pass it to my java code?

Answer (score 1):

By default `Date()` gives you the system time only. So if your application is deployed in tomcat the `Date()` object will give you the tomcat time which is also the local system time.

You can convert it to any format. One of the example is below

```
Date date = new Date();
DateTimeFormat dtf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
Window.alert(dtf.format(date, TimeZone.createTimeZone(0)));
```